# Need to identify correct confidence interval

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, sampling

A manufacturer of precision gaskets makes gaskets in two grades A and B. In A, the precision gaskets thickness is far more critical than in B. The production run for A is very small, whereas the production run for B is very large.
What should be the right confidence intervals for testing the thickness of A & B ? What should be the appropriate sample size?
My understanding is that a higher confidence interval makes more sense if the precision of attribute is important. Can somebody help me here please?

Comment: Are you asking which confidence level you should be using (ie 99%, 95%, etc)? Can you indicate how large a big/small production run is? Do you have any estimates for variation in gasket thickness? Please add them to your question if you do

Comment: Hi jros, unfortunately I have no further information. As a part of my coursework, I've been asked to suggest the appropriate confidence intervals based on the above info. And yes the question is if the thickness has to be highly accurate, should I go for 80%, 90%, 95% or 99% confidence interval?

Comment: Which sounds like the highest accuracy to you?

Comment: To me it seems like 99% confidence interval would be the best possible constraint. still wanted to confirm if i was missing something

Comment: @IndigoChild a 99% confidence interval is the widest practical confidence interval, so it could offer stronger proof to reject null hypotheses depending on your analyses than thinner intervals

Comment: Required but not supplied is the cost benefit of having outsized thicknesses for either A or B. For example, it nothing costly happens if A is out of scope for thickness that is not equivalent to 1000 people dying because A is outsized. Only the cost benefit can determine if confidence intervals are even appropriate. If the cost is extremely high for outsized A, then post hoc thickness testing, rather than confidence intervals would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this is a coursework question so this answer may not be very useful but here we go...

I wonder whether the confidence interval is the right statistic to decide whether the manufacturing process is good enough. The problem is that increasing sample size will reduce the CI and eventually you will virtually always reject the null hypothesis.

Regarding the width of the CI, if you want to ensure the process is good enough and you want to be conservative, perhaps you want to choose a narrow CI, like 80%. A narrow CI means that you consider a smaller range of (true) means as compatible with the observed data so a narrow CI gives you more stringent quality control.

---

Perhaps an alternative approach could be to assume that thickness measures come from a known distribution, e.g. Gaussian, with unknown parameters values. Then from your sample of i.i.d. observations you can estimate the parameters of the probability density function and get the probability that a gasket is within an accepted interval of thickness.

For example, your sample has mean = 11 and sd = 1 and you tolerate thinckness between 8 and 12. Then you have 0.1% chance of producing a gasket too thin and 16% chance of producing a gasket too thick (R code below). (*Questions I'm not sure about just now: How large has the sample size to be to ensure a good enough estimate of mean and sd? How do you add margins of error around the % chance above?*)

```
(too_low <- integrate(dnorm, -Inf, 8, mean= 11, sd= 1))
(too_high <- integrate(dnorm, 12, Inf, mean= 11, sd= 1))
```

Comment: Really helpful insights, thanks a lot!